# Html, tag form similar to StackOverflow's one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: my form]

this is how my form behave when i insert several tags but i want it to be like the one of this site. As you can see the scroll bar appears and a new is created. how can i keep everything on the same row?

http://jsfiddle.net/H86Zy/2/

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us to see your code in action ?

Comment: Well, with the generated markup it seems pretty difficult. But if you want to keep a long list of tags on one line, at some point, you will have an horizontal scrollbar, is this acceptable ?

Comment: Better than nothing, but just take a look at the tag form of stackoverflow, i want it to be exactly that way and has no scrollbar. I can spend some time reworking the code if necessary and if it's not overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an height is defined, so the containing `<div />` keeps its height and a scrollbar appears.

In the css, remove the height rule for the class .taginput:

```
div.tagsinput {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background: #FFF;
    padding:5px;
    width:300px;
    /*height:100px;*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The plugin also has a default value of 100px so you have to set the option when initializing:

```
$('#tagbox_a_1').tagsInput({ height: 'auto' });
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/aqd33/) to illustrate.